# I've been following this tutorial on making really cool 'Twisting Crystals' in Blender, but the Colorramp seems to be broken for some strange reason

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, shaders, color, shader-nodes

I'm at 19:20 timestamp in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uRAfhJQFjRo&t=1160s) video tutorial, and while the color on the left side of the Colorramp seems to be working perfectly, no matter how I change the color on the right, it doesn't seem to be effecting my mesh at all. What could be the issue? (My project can be downloaded on [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sGgrP0EGAlwB8daulgjzvrviMVTbXKDy/view) Google Drive link, you can set the viewport shading to rendered and try changing both colors).

[image]

As you can see, no matter how I change the color on the right side of the Colorramp, my mesh remains uneffected.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Polyfjord has pinned this comment already two years ago, have a look below the video:

*Important update for Blender v2.90: The node setup with the gradient color at 19:48 will no longer move properly with the mesh in the updated version. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be an easy way to fix this for beginners. However, there are still a lot to learn in this tutorial even if you have to skip the gradient colors! Try experimenting with colorful lights instead, and simply use a strong solid color of your choice. If you are a beginner and you absolutely love colorful gradients, you can always follow this tutorial in Blender v2.82 or earlier. Thanks for watching!*

*For advanced users: A UV unwrapping with projection set to 'project from view' (when viewing the mesh from the side) should do the trick. Use Edit Mode and UV Editor if you need to tweak it. The mapping of the texture can then be set to UV and should follow the mesh perfectly!*

Comment: edit: actually it looks like it's the bevel modifier that makes the gradient fail, I don't know why...

Comment: Ah, so I basically have to skip it, then. Welp that's unfortunate. Thanks anyway! :)

Comment: @Tom Yes, it looks like it. Well, sorry this was no proper solution, I basically wanted to tell you it seems you haven't done anything wrong from the tutorial, it just doesn't work like that anymore.

Comment: @moonboots Ah I see, well I didn't have time to dig deeper into the tutorial and don't remember all from when I saw it. Maybe you can make it work somehow without the UV mapping that Polyfjord suggested in his comment?